# How do I check the existence of the EOF in char?

Tags: c, char, eof

How do I check the existence of the EOF in the name field of the following structure?

```
struct dirent * ent;
ent->d_name;
```

i.e. I want to know if `ent->d_name` owns the EOF.

On the other hand, could initialize the variable is of type `char[256]`

```
ent->d_name[255]='\0';
```

But I get the following warning:

```
warning: can be used 'ent' uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Comment: It's right, you didn't initialize it.  What does "owns the EOF" mean?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: What do you mean by existence of EOF or ownership of EOF?  It's normally a property of streams, and there is no stream here at all.

Comment: `EOF` is (a macro that expands to) a negative `int` value returned by `getchar()` when it encounters an end-of-file or error condition. I don't believe it applies here.

Comment: @eduardosufan `eof` means *end of file* and it isn't represented by a `char`. Instead, you can check for a null-terminated `char` which essentially is the same thing.

Comment: @eduardosufan What are you trying to do? list files in a directory and read all the content of regular files (in which case reading of the file has to go until you reach [EOF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782080/what-is-eof-in-the-c-programming-language))?

Comment: d_name is the name of a file, and due to malfunctions at the opening of it, I started to wonder if there was the EOF. I read the documentation of dirent.h (where is the structure) and the d_name field contains EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the uninitialized warning because you didn't initialize the value `ent` would point to. `struct dirent * ent` is merely a pointer that should point to a `struct dirent` but you haven't initialized the memory it points to. In order to use `ent` either `malloc` it:

```
struct dirent * ent = malloc(sizeof(*ent));
```

or allocate it on the stack and get a pointer to it using the address-of operator:

```
struct dirent ent;
struct dirent * entPointer = &ent;
```

As to the EOF question: the `EOF` macro can be used to detect an end-of-file in a stream, such as one opened by `fopen`. It is not relevant to the string `d_name[255]`. Unless you mean the terminating-`'\0'`, which is guaranteed to be there. [citation needed]

Comment: Tank you. EOF is in d_name (I read the documentation of dirent.h, containing the structure)