# fgets() goes into infinite loop reading from stdin

Tags: c, stdin, infinite-loop, fgets

I wrote the following code, but it gets stuck into an infinite loop. Can somebody help me out at this topic?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char s[10];


    fp=fopen("text1.txt", "w");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin)!=NULL)//Reads until the NULL character.
        fputs(s, fp);//Write to the file pointed by fp..


    fclose(fp);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: How do you terminate the input? I.e., how do you tell your program that it has reached "end of file" for the input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782080/what-is-eof-in-the-c-programming-language

Comment: Error messages matter: `perror( "text1.txt" )`.  Better yet: `fp = fopen( argv[1], "w"); if ( fp == NULL ) { perror( argv[1] ); exit EXIT_FAILURE; }`

Comment: The final `getch` is pretty pointless, since the while loop will consume all of the input.

Comment: In ubuntu,The above code works fine with `ctrl-D` when preceded by a `newline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program will run, as expected, until the input signals "end of file".

If you're not using input redirection (e.g. running it as `myprogram < somefile.txt`) but instead running with the console (keyboard) as the input device, you must manually signal end of file to cause the loop to end.

In Linux, this is done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, in Windows it's <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

If you are typing in the input use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to terminate the input.I tried the code on linux and it works fine.<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> represents EOF on windows.

If you are not typing in input and using redirection,the code works fine as such.