# how to let the program know that the file ends when I use while(cin>> )

Tags: c++

when I use `while(cin>> ){}` in my program how to end the input?
I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, but none of them work. outputs of both `cin>>^Z` and `cin>>^D` are true.

How to let the program know that the file ends? How to pass NUL character such that the output of `cin>>` be false and while end?

Comment: what are you accepting with `cin` ?

Comment: This is not a C++ issue, but one for your terminal program.  You should share your OS and terminal....

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on linux machine and Ctrl+d works fine.If you are using Mac OS you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364313/signal-eof-in-mac-osx-terminal)