# Golang: How to terminate the bufio Scan() from terminal?

Tags: go

I am running the [dup1 example](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch1/dup1/main.go) from [The Go Programming Language](http://www.gopl.io/) book (related code shown below):

```
for input.Scan() {
    counts[input.Text()]++
}
```

After typing some lines of text, I want to terminate the `Scan()` method. I've tried Ctrl+D, Ctrl+Z and many other key combinations without luck. Only Ctrl+C works but that also terminates the program.

How can I terminate the `Scan()` from terminal without exiting the program?

I am developing on Windows 7 using os.Stdin.

[Edit]

`Ctrl+Z` doesn't work:

Thanks. But that doesn't work for me:

```
C:\prj\src\gopl\>go run dup1.go
I have tried all these combinations from the terminal
^Z
^X
^V
^B
^N

^A
^D
^F
^G

^K
^L
^Q
^W
^E
^R
^T
^Y
^U
^O
^P
2(Notes: only Ctrl + C works here)

C:\prj\src\gopl\>
```

If I run this program in Ubuntu, only `Ctrl + D` works, `Ctrl + Z` will **Stop** the program and `Ctrl + C` will terminate it.

Comment: Under Windows the `EOF` is mapped Ctrl+Z as far as I know. Maybe your terminal remap it to something else, check out its configuration.

Comment: Are you sure you're typing Ctrl+Z at the *beginning of a new line*? That may be required for Scan to actually receive EOF.

Answer (score 11):

No one asked but I had this problem in OSX and this came up in a search. Mac OSX terminals recognize EOF when control-D is pressed at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 5):

`ctrl + shift + d` will send EOF to the terminal if it's the first character in a new line.

```
go run main.go

> line one
> another line
> another line
> ctrl + shift + d
```

And you should see the output

```
2 another line
```

As described in this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/21658005/1522019 .
You can use `stty all` to find EOF combination. I kept doing `ctrl + d` which in my mind is the same as `ctrl + D`.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, on a new line,

```
<Ctrl+Z><Enter>
```

Comment: This is typically what's used for EOF in C, although I ran into the same issue above with golang on Windows 7.

Comment: Worked for Windows10 command line.
Ctrl+Z (prints ^Z) + Enter.
Thanks!