# Read lines until EOF into pointer in C

Tags: c, fgets, eof

I know there are hundreds of topics about it, but I need to ask again.
I do have the following code:

```
char *str;

while(fgets(&str,50,stdin) != NULL && &str != EOF) {
    printf(&str);
}
printf("Test");
```

I would like to read several lines in my code and do something with them. In that example it's just printing.
I would like to end, when there is an EOF and then do other stuff after the while-loop.
Unfortunately, in the moment when I am using CMD-D (EOF on mac/CLion), the complete program terminates, no matter whats afterwords, so there is no "Test" at the output anymore.

Does anyone know whats happening? Also note, that I need it as a char pointer, because I want to work with it later.

Comment: That piece of code is problematic for multiple reasons, including you not knowing what [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) really does or how it works. The same with [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). You should probably listen to what your compiler tells you more closely, it should complain loudly about code like that. And then take a few steps back, get a beginners book and start over from the very beginning.

Comment: How could this be upvoted? It is reading **50** characters inside a pointer, where the size of a pointer is never greater than 8 on common architecture! This invokes UB and behaviour is... **undefined** :-(

Comment: You do not have allocated memory to `str`. You do not need to use the address of operator (`&`) on `str` when you pass it to `fgets`.

Comment: "*I know there are hundreds of topics about it, but I need to ask again.*" I disagree. Also, "*Does anyone know what's happening?*" is far too broad / unspecific.

Comment: Don't read lines "into" a pointer.   Ensure `str` actually points at (the first element of) an array that has 50 elements.   Then pass `str` as the first argument of `fgets()`, not `&str`.   `printf(&str)` would ALSO need to be `printf("%s", str)`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you giving me some comments about it, also to gsamaras for correcting my typo mistake.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `str` is just a pointer that doesn't point to allocated memory. Then you ask [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) to store in `str` what it read (but where to store it, since there is no memory allocated for `str`?!). This causes *Undefined Behavior*, and must be fixed.

A simple solution would be to make `str` an array of characters.

The `EOF` you have in your code shows that you didn't read the manual of the function, which states:

> **Return value**:
>
> If the end-of-file is encountered while attempting to
>   read a character, the eof indicator is set (feof). If this happens
>   before any characters could be read, *the pointer returned is a null
>   pointer* (and the contents of str remain unchanged).

That means that we do not need an extra check.

Putting everything together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[50];
    while (fgets(str, 50, stdin)) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which reads the file line by line, and then prints every line.

---

Useful link: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).

---

PS: You could use as the second argument of `fgets()` `sizeof(str)`, instead of 50 (the size of the array), but that wouldn't work when `str` is a pointer that actually points to another location that the memory is stored (for example another array).

Comment: Use `sizeof(str)` as second argument of `fgets()`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for answering me! The example with the File reading which you just deleted a couple of minutes ago helped me to understand a little bit more about it. But my last question would be: How can I see via stdin that the user terminated his entries, so is there something like EOF there as well, or is that just for "real files" to read?

Comment: I updated the answer @FranzFerdinand, because your question was with `stdin`. Would you like me to revert it? As for your question, you just give `EOF` from your terminal, `ctrl + D` in Linux and it [should be the same in Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364313/signal-eof-in-mac-osx-terminal).

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's stdin or a file, because my question would be quite the same on both. Thank you very much for your help, so it was a misunderstanding of using EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like:

```
char str[50];

while(fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin) != NULL) {
    printf("%s",str);
}
printf("Test");
```

Comment: Rather than `50` as the second argument of `fgets()`, better to use `sizeof(str)`.   This only works if `str` is an array though (not if it is a pointer).  `fgets()` cannot return `EOF` - check what it ACTUALLY returns on error.

Comment: Oops... fixed EOF-->NULL

Comment: Hey, thanks for that idea, so in fact I misunderstood something about the pointers. But there is one question left for me: When I am reading from stdin, how do I determine EOF happening then?

Comment: @FranzFerdinand On end-of-file or input error, `fgets()` returns `NULL`.