# How can I raise an EOF error?

Tags: python, exception, eoferror

I am a newbie learning python. Please take a look at the below code (From Data Structures and Algorithms in Python by Goodrich, et al).

```
age = -1   # an initially invalid choice
while age <= 0:
    try:
        age = int(input('Enter your age in years: '))
        if age <= 0:
            print('Your age must be positive.')
    except ValueError:
        print('That is an invalid age specification.')
    except EOFError:
        print('There was an unexpected error reading input.')
        raise  # let's re-raise this exception.
```

I know what ValueError is. For example the ValueError occurs if the input is given as characters instead of an integer.

On the other hand, I have no idea when EOFError raises.

1. I can't get what 're-raise this exception' means
2. The book says, 'the call to input will raise an EOFError if the console input fails.' Again, I have no idea what console input is and when console input fails.

I have tried several ways of raising EOFError, but every time I tried there was only ValueError. Can someone give me some idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`input`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> When `EOF` is read, `EOFError` is raised.

`EOF` is sent when the input stream reaches the end, or if it's from the console, it means the user presses ctrl-D on *NIX, or ctrl-Z on Windows.

You can catch the `EOFError` exception and break your `while` loop as a way to end the program gracefully, so change your exception block to:

```
except EOFError:
    print('Done.')
    break
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how to catch the EOFError? What input should be?

Comment: The `except EOFError` block catches `EOFError`. If you want to test it, simply press ctrl-D on *NIX, or ctrl-Z on Windows, and then enter.

Comment: Um... Im using mac and command-D or Z did not work as wanted.

Comment: Result of command-D: Enter your age in years: 
That is an invalid age specification.
Enter your age in years:

Comment: result of command-Z: Enter your age in years: That is an invalid age specification.

Comment: Command-D should work on OS X. Not sure why it doesn't work for you. See: [Signal EOF in mac osx terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364313/signal-eof-in-mac-osx-terminal)

Comment: I test with pycharm under win10 and `ctrl + d` will cause `EOFError`.

Answer (score 2):

You caught the exception, meaning Python will continue with the loop instead of letting the exception percolate up the stack, ultimately ending the program if it remains uncaught. Calling `raise` without an argument in an `except` clause simply raises the same exception again, equivalent to

```
except EOFError as exc:
    print("Unexpected error")
    raise exc
```

Re-raising the exception is necessary if you don't actually *handle* the exception, instead simply adding additional logging before (possibly) someone else handles it.

*Triggering* the `EOFError` can be done by running

```
$ python -c 'input()' < /dev/null
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

as all attempts to read from `/dev/null` look like an attempt to read from the end of a file.

Comment: I'm sorry but when I enter $ python -c 'input()' < /dev/null as an input, it still says it is ValueError, maybe because it is a string?

Comment: I get an `EOFError` in both Python 2 and Python 3; not sure how you are getting a `ValueError`.

Comment: Have you copied and pasted the code and entered the input as $ python -c 'input()' < /dev/null?

Comment: In addition, if I run $ python -c 'input()' < /dev/null in the blank editor, the result would be Syntax Error: invalid syntax: <string>, line 1, pos 1

Comment: The command (minus the `$`) is meant to be run from the shell, not from inside the interpreter. The `$` is just a convention for indicating a shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to raise a
*The following code will produce a Syntax Error*, EOF in Python:

```
print("Where's EOF now?")
#### this is a test to see where the EOF occurs... suspect is that it will be EOF line 4
print("Hello world!"
```

I'm not sure if this is what you mean by "raise an error", though. *Creates a new post in StackOverflow*