# Why does my program print something before it ends when I press ctrl + D?

Tags: c, while-loop, eof, feof

So I wrote a simple program that converts a decimal to binary, that only accepts positive whole numbers. So numbers like -2 and 1.1 would output "Sorry, that's not a positive whole number." It infinitely asks the user to input a number until the user presses `ctrl + D`. However when I tested it it prints out the "Sorry..." statement before it ends the program.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void DecToBin(int userInput){
    int binary[32];
    int i = 0;
    while (userInput > 0) {
        binary[i] = userInput % 2;
        userInput /= 2;
        i++;
    }
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
        printf("%d", binary[j]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    double userDec;
    int temp;

    printf("Starting the Decimal to Binary Converter!\n\n");

    while(!feof(stdin)) {
        printf("Please enter a positive whole number (or EOF to quit): ");
        scanf("%lf", &userDec);
        temp = (int)(userDec);
        if ((userDec > 0) && (temp / userDec == 1)) {
            printf("\n\t%.0lf (base-10) is equivalent to ", userDec);
            DecToBin(userDec);
            printf(" (base-2)!\n\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("\tSorry, that was not a positive whole number.\n");
        } 
    }
    printf("\n\tThank you for using the Decimal to Binary Generator.\n");
    printf("Goodbye!\n\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

(All the tab and newlines are just how it's supposed to be formatted so don't pay attention to that)
So from what I'm understanding, my program reads `ctrl + D` as the else in my while loops. So, any idea why that is?

Comment: If you don't want to accept floats, then why scan for a float and convert it to integer instead of just scanning for an integer?

Comment: Plus, you should try to produce a [mre]. I'm pretty confident that you would have the same behavior without calling `DecToBin`? It's very unlikely that it is causing this.

Comment: @klutt My instructions tell me to that numbers 11.0 should work, so that is why. But my problem is the EOF thing, I believe everything else is good.

Comment: And why would it not print that? Do you expect it to got to the other branch in the if statement?

Comment: @klutt I thought when it would get the command `ctrl + D` it would stop and print the statements outside the while loop?

Comment: Blindly assuming `scanf` succeeds isn't helping matters. It's pointless to do *anything* following that statement if the call result isn't `1` (and maybe that should factor into your loop control).

Comment: @osito_solito Normally I don't have opinions on which answer a user chooses to accept, but Omairs answer does not even solve your problem at all. ;)

Comment: Another thing to think of for your next question is that if you feel that you should write *"All the tab and newlines are just how it's supposed to be formatted so don't pay attention to that"*, remember that it's usually better to just edit the printouts so that there's no reason to write that comment at all. But interesting question. Somehow I can understand why this confusion comes from, even though it's very obvious when you're more seasoned. Very interesting. Because even though I know it's not the case and why, but I **want** C-d to work that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you think C-d would trigger some kind of break in the code. Like the keyword `break`. This is not true.

Read this post to see what's happening when you press C-d: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21365313/6699433

That does not cause anything special to happen in the C code. `scanf` will simply not read anything. After the `scanf` statement, the code will continue as usual, so the code WILL unconditionally enter the `if` statement.

This is also a pretty severe thing, because you'll be using `userDec` uninitialized. `scanf` returns the number of successful assignments, and you should always check the return value. So in your case you want this:

```
if(scanf("%lf", &userDec) != 1) { /* Handle error */ }
```

Because if `scanf` does not return 1, `userDec` is unassigned.

To achieve what you want, simply do this:

```
if(scanf("%lf", &userDec) != 1)
    break;
```

Comment: [Control-D does not send an end-of-file condition. It sends pending data immediately instead of waiting for enter/return: It terminates the current read operation, sending whatever data has been typed. If no data has been typed, the stream may interpret that as end-of-file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21365313/298225)