# Why does the use of fgets result in an infinite loop when Ctrl-d is pressed?

Tags: c, fgets

The program below prompts the user to input something. If the input is acceptable to `fgets`, the program will print what the user had input. The program works, except that something strange happens when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> at the prompt. When the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> at the prompt, the program enters an infinite loop where the prompt gets printed over and over again. Why does this happen?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFSIZE 512

int main(void)
{
    char input_buf[BUFSIZE];
    char *user_input;
    while (1) {
        user_input = NULL;
        printf("Input: ");  /* Prompt. */
        if ((user_input = fgets(input_buf, BUFSIZE, stdin)) == NULL) {
            printf("Invalid input. Try again.\n");
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("User input: %s", user_input);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `continue` isn't the best choice when `stdin` is closed?

Comment: `while(1)` is an infinite loop if you never break out of it

Comment: once the user enters `Control-D` `fgets` will return `NULL` forever. Then your program will `continue`. Only until `1` changes to another thing, which will take, well, forever...

Comment: @arfneto Why will `fgets` return `NULL` forever after the user presses Ctrl-d?

Comment: on closing `stdin` ... `control-z` on some platforms

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue reading (or trying to) after an apparent end of file, insert `clearerr(stdin);` before `continue;`.

Pressing <kbd>Control-D</kbd> in a Unix system with default terminal settings sends whatever the user has currently typed to the process. If the user has not typed anything new (which happens when  <kbd>Control-D</kbd> is pressed at the beginning of a line or just after another <kbd>Control-D</kbd>), the process receives zero characters, and the C stream software treats this as a soft end-of-file indication.

Then further I/O attempts on the stream report end-of-file until you clear the “error.”

(Further information on what <kbd>Control-D</kbd> does is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21365313/298225).)