# Verify that the expression getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1, ctrl-D gets "0D", not "0"

Tags: c

i am learning The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie (2nd edition), Exercise 1.06 on page 17

my question is why everytime i enter ctrl-d, it prints "0D", not "0", my computer is iMAC m1 chip. thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("%d\n", getchar() != EOF);
}
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364313/signal-eof-in-mac-osx-terminal. But I wouldn't know, since I would never even consider a mac for (the purpose of learning) programming...

Answer (score 4):

The reason for your observations is when you type <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> the terminal echoes `^D` and 2 backspaces (BS) and returns `4` immediately.  The effect is the cursor is on the `^` character on the screen and when `printf` outputs `0` and a newline, the `0` overwrites the `^` and the newline is converted to a CR+LF, causing the cursor to go to the beginning of the next line.

You can modify your program to avoid this problem by printing a newline before the `%d` conversion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("\n%d\n", getchar() != EOF);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
^D
0
```