# Why does Ctrl-J and Ctrl-M return 10 in c programming on OSX?

Tags: c, macos

Consider this thread [What is EOF in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782080/what-is-eof-in-the-c-programming-language)

The answer was that `EOF` (Ctrl-D) results in that `getchar` returns -1

- My question is what does Ctrl-J and Ctrl-M represent in c on OSX and why does `getchar` return 10 for both using the same code as in link above?
- What other shortcuts (Ctrl-somthing / Cmd-something) results in that `getchar`turns a static predefined number?

Comment: What are you doing so that MacOS X returns anything? Be a bit more precise. We can't read your mind.

Comment: Just testing the same code as in thread with other shortcuts. I use the shortcuts as an additional way to control the flow of a program. I am just curious where the 10 comes from and whether it Ctrl-J/M always returns 10 and if there are other shortcuts like it.

Comment: Please read the other answer more carefully. It doesn't say `EOF (Ctrl-D) returns -1`, in the contrary. It says that pressing the keybord sequence `Ctrl-D` signals the end of the stream, which then makes that `getchar` returns `EOF`. `EOF` is a special value to notify the caller that the end of file is reach. Often this `EOF` value is `-1` but could be any other negative value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdin` is typically in text mode. Various conversions occur per OS concerning line endings when reading/writing in text mode. Crtl-M is one of them - it is converted to 10. Had IO been in binary mode, no conversion would be expected.

Consoles map various keyboard combinations to various `char` and actions (like Ctrl-D --> EOF). The various `char` created certainly include most of the values 0 to 127. As these values are typically mapped to [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), the first 32 values (Ctrl-@, CTRL-A, CTRl-B, ... Ctrl-_), they may have no graphical representation

Note: Notice what is returned when `getchar()` is called again after it returned `EOF`. Expect it to immediately return `EOF` again without waiting for any additionally key presses. (Ctrl-D) set a condition, not a char.

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl-J is the shortcut for the line feed control character, having the character code 10. [Here](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html) is a page with other control characters

I as of this time do not know why Ctrl-M (ASCII value 13) returns 10 but assume it is due to it being similar in function to the line feed.

The reason EOF returns -1 is because its value is -1 on most systems.

Some other defined characters:
Ctrl-G: 7
Ctrl-I: 9
...
Ctrl-V: 22

Comment: +1. Add more information for Ctrl-M.

Comment: Thanks, but I primarily interested in the return. See the link above. Ctrl-D always returns -1 in c on OSX. Are there other shortcuts that ALWAYS return a predefined number?

Comment: @userjuice If you follow the provided link you will find the control codes and the attributed integer values of such.

Comment: When I press Ctrl-M `getchar` returns 10 for me and not 13. `getchar` doesn't return anything when I press Ctrl-V. According to your list Also according to the list you linked to `getchar`should return 4 when Ctrl-D is pressed but it returns -1.

Comment: @userjuice As I have said in my answer I am unsure why it is returning ten but I believe it has something to do with the Line Feed ("\n") and the Carriage Return ("\r") character having similar behavior. Here's an article on newlines: [Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages)

Comment: The actual value of EOF is system-dependent (but is commonly -1) -Wikipedia

Comment: The thread I linked to states that the EOF is system-dependent, but static(?). My main question if there are others. So far I have only found Ctrl-J and Ctrl-M that oddly enough seem to have`getchar`return the same value 10.

Comment: `stdin` is typically in text mode.  Various conversions occur per OS concerning line endings when reading/writing in text mode.  Crtl-M is one of them - it is converted to 10.  Had IO been in binary mode, no conversion would be expected.

Comment: @chux THANKS!! Finally some answers. But why are most Ctrl-SomeLetter blank?

Comment: @userjuicer Your console maps various keyboard combinations to various `char` and actions (like Ctrl-D --> EOF).  The various `char` created certainly include most of the values 0 to 127.  As these values are _typically_ mapped to [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), the first 32 values (Ctrl-@, CTRLA, CTRl-B, ... Ctrl-_) may have no graphical representation.

Comment: @chux Again thanks! That was the answer I was looking for.