# Why EOF doesn't terminate the program?

Tags: loops

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    char i;
   do{
        scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
        printf("%d\n",b-a);
    }while(a!=EOF);
   return 0;
}
```

In this program when i press ctrl+z(EOF) it doesn't terminate.It print the last value and continue until I close the output console manually.What's the problem here?

Comment: but i take -1 two times to terminate.and i wanna do it with EOF.would you please tell me what's wrong with EOF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782080/what-is-eof-in-the-c-programming-language

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kill the program you have to press  Control+C instead of  Control+Z.

Here, The program iterates without stopping because it couldn't find a!=EOF condition. Because a is a address of memory location and the difference between those addresses never equals to EOF character. Therefore it iterates untill timeout.

Comment: But if I press Control+C it doesn't terminate from program but the output console will be closed.

Comment: Ya. because it couldn't find a!=EOF condition.