# How does the EOF macro work with getchar?

Tags: c, eof, getchar

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    int ch;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "w");
    printf("Enter data");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putc(ch, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "w");
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

How does the first `while` loop stop inputting from user? 
Since there is `EOF` present as a condition.

Or else do I need to `use` for loop?

Comment: `ch` **must** be defined as `int`.

Comment: 2nd `fp=fopen("input.txt","w");` : `"w"` --> `"r"`

Comment: same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782080/what-is-eof-in-the-c-programming-language

Comment: `int main` not `void main`.

Comment: I don't understand what this question is about. Please reformat the question in this way: *"The program is showing /behavior X/.  I am puzzled, because I am expecting /behavior Y/."*   In other words, what is or is not happening relative to your expectation?

Comment: EOF is not a function. Question is meaningless. Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: @FUZxxl ch should be defined as int if you want your program to both compile and work

Comment: I suspect the question really is 'why doesnt this program work'. pmg  and BLUEPIXY have given answers

Answer (score 4):

`EOF` is a value, not a function. It is essentially defined as a macro.

For reference, from `C11`, chapter §7.21.1, `<stdio.h>`

> `EOF`
>   which expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value, that
>   is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a
>   stream;[...]

In case, [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) fails, it will return a value which is defined as `EOF`.

Quoting from the manual page (*emphasis mine*)

> `fgetc()`, `getc()` and `getchar()` return the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or **EOF on end of file or error.**

`EOF` represents a value that may not fit into a `char` type. You must use `int` type for `ch` variable.

> *How does the first while loop stop inputting from user?*

use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on linux, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on windows.

Comment: @OmkarPednekar what prints on screen? In case `getchar()` fails, it will return EOF, and the condition will be false.

Comment: In the second while loop i am printing the data in the file on screen

Comment: @OmkarPednekar Have you changed `char ch;` to `int ch;` as suggested in the answer?

Comment: @OmkarPednekar Try typing CTRL+Z