# fgetwc EOF loop test fails, but 65535 OK

Tags: c++, c, loops, testing, eof

VS10 & MCBS:

For this I have created a file called *c:\eoftest* containing the text *"test"*. The value of ch on the 5th pass in the following code is 65535 returned by fgetwc, but it does not equate to EOF, which we all know is defined in stdio.h as (-1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    int ch;
    FILE *stream = NULL;
    wchar_t buf[5];
    memset (buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
    stream = _wfopen(L"C:\\eoftest.txt", L"r");

            for (int i = 0; (i  < (sizeof(buf) - 1) && ((ch = fgetwc(stream)) != EOF) && (ch != '\0')); i++) //we are reading so last null condition mandatory
            {
            ungetwc(ch, stream);
            buf[i] = (wchar_t)(ch = fgetwc(stream));
            }
}
```

Replacing the condition (sic) with `(ch = fgetwc(stream)) != 65535)` works in this case, but what is not done to ensure the EOF test can succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN documentation for [fgetc, fgetwc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7sskzc1.aspx)

> **`fgetc`** returns the character read as an **`int`** or returns **`EOF`** to indicate an error or end of file. **`fgetwc`** returns, as a
>   **`wint_t`**, the wide character that corresponds to the character read or
>   returns **`WEOF`** to indicate an error or end of file.

`WEOF` is defined as `0xFFFF` which is what you substituted earlier `65535`

```
#define WEOF ((wint_t)(0xFFFF))
```

So the `EOF` test for wide char should be changed to

```
if ((ch = fgetwc(stream)) != WEOF) ...
```

---

Edit

```
int main()
{
    wchar_t buf[5];
    memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
    wcscpy(buf, L"1234");

    FILE *stream = _wfopen(L"C:\\eoftest.txt", L"rb");
    if (!stream)
    {
        stream = _wfopen(L"C:\\eoftest.txt", L"w+b");
        if (!stream)
        {
            printf("cannot create file\n");
            return 0;
        }

        fwrite((char*)buf, sizeof(buf[0]), wcslen(buf), stream);
        fseek(stream, 0, 0);
    }

    int len = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(buf[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        wchar_t ch = fgetwc(stream);
        if (ch == WEOF) break;
        buf[i] = ch;
    }

    wprintf(L"result = %s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit 2: This will print content of unicode file line by line:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *stream = _wfopen(L"c:\\test\\test.txt", L"rb");
    if (!stream) return 0;

    int buflen = 256;
    wchar_t* buf = (wchar_t*)malloc(buflen * sizeof(wchar_t));

    if (fread(buf, 2, 1, stream))
    {
        if (buf[0] != 0xFEFF)
        {
            //BOM not detected, go back to start of file
            rewind(stream);
        }//else, skip the first 2 bytes
    }

    int i = 0, line = 0;
    wint_t ch = 0;
    while (ch != WEOF)
    {
        ch = fgetwc(stream);
        if (ch == L'\n' || ch == WEOF)
        {
            //null-terminate the buffer at i
            buf[i] = L'\0';

            //trim the '\r' at the end, if any
            if (i > 0 && buf[i - 1] == '\r') buf[i - 1] = L'\0';

            wprintf(L"%3d %s\n", ++line, buf);

            //start a new line for the next pass
            i = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            buf[i] = ch;
            i++;
            if (i == buflen)
            {
                //increase buffer:
                buflen += 256;
                buf = (wchar_t*)realloc(buf, buflen * sizeof(wchar_t));
            }
        }
    }

    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. Must be a "recent" addition to the MSDN library as it's only on [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a04aab7y.aspx) of the first 10 pages googled for "MSDN" and "EOF".

Comment: By the way, I just noticed `buf` is declared as wide char, `sizeof(buf)` is 10 bytes, and buf has 5 elements. You probably want `sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0])` which is `5` --- Also you may want to open the unicode file as binary. See edit.

Comment: t would be interesting to find out what is more efficient for large files, going back a step with ungetwc in the OP or the suggested alternative of defining a char each time in the loop. Also prefer to do binary, but have only seen examples regarding the use of tokens or delimiters in text files (I used fwprintf)- albeit material for another SO question.

Comment: I see what you are doing. But don't do that. Disk operations are slow and should be minimized. Using 3 disk operations to read one character is 3 times slower. Ideally you should read more than one byte at the time. You have to open the unicode file as binary (you can still use `fwprintf`) Either that or set special unicode flags and markers, but don't open Unicode file as text file (ANSI)

Comment: But isn't the default NTFS block size 4kb or thereabouts? According to this [ancient post](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=622897) the OS always uses read-ahead caching. Heck this is getting into stuff I know very little about, - but agree that the three reads on the physical disk for one character is not the way to go. Would the recommended size of a single read be greater than 4kb?

Comment: No, reading the file one character at the time is slower. Windows does cache files but it cannot load everything in to memory just in case you may want to access it. It's better to avoid unnecessary disk access --- I added another example that should print unicode file line by line. There are also other example, you can lookup `fgets` examples, change the functions to unicode, `fgetws` etc. Just make sure you open the file in binary and watch out for `wchar_t` which is 2 bytes as opposed to a regular `char` which is 1 byte.

Comment: Thanks a lot,- getchar is used in this [example](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=FgMsCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=getline+binary+c&source=bl&ots=EicDBbe27A&sig=daukBgMScATfCBocRbc_0EbLYM0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh55aHycTKAhUJoZQKHYrHDyM4HhDoAQhSMAk#v=onepage&q=getline%20binary%20c&f=false) for stdio. Same kind of thing? BTW in the second example, ch is `wint_t`?

Comment: Yes that was meant to be `win_t`. I updated the answer based on the link which you posted, so now it should work for any UTF16 Unicode file. Note that this is pure C not C++, you have to change the file extension to `*.c` instead of `*.cpp` Another difference in C is that you don't need a cast for `malloc` and `realloc`