# Getting unlimited input in C?

Tags: c, windows, input, mingw

So I'm trying to program a function which allows the user to enter an unlimited amount of chars. For example this:

```
char string[100]
```

limits the input to 100 characters.

The code i have so far is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* uinput(){
    char *string, *current;
    int counter = 0;
    string = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    do{
        realloc(string, counter * sizeof(char));
        current = string + counter;
        *current = getchar();
        counter++;
    }while(*current != '\n');
    return string;
}

int main(){
    char *s;
    s = uinput();
    printf("\nYou entered: %s", *s);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to pointers, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work(Program crashes). What I'm trying to do is keep reading a character and keep relocating  the string pointer so the amount of bytes keeps increasing until the user presses enter ('\n').

Thanks
~Raf

Comment: The function `getline` is the easy answer.  It was originally a glibc extension (i.e. not C standard library), but it should be supported under mingw too.  If you ever need to worry about being cross-platform, then it can be reimplemented using fgets and realloc.

Comment: @rafaelThedoublemaster there are lots of problems with the code, I am writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is sane, but there are minor details that are wrong. If you compile with warnings enabled, you'd notice that you're missing `<stdlib.h>`; also you're giving the *first character* to `printf` instead of the pointer to the buffer.

Then there is the obvious bug that your size is reset to 0, and you're [casting the return value of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), using `char` to store the result of `getchar()` which is also wrong because you cannot check against `EOF`. You're not saving the `realloc`ed pointer; and you're not terminating the string properly. On minor detail, you'd want to double the size of buffer in each `realloc`, because `realloc` needs to potentially copy the whole line, so it becomes slower and slower over time as the line grows in length.

Thus we get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* uinput() {
    char *string;
    // number of characters in the buffer
    size_t counter = 0;

    // size of allocated buffer
    size_t allocated = 16;
       
    int c;
    string = malloc(allocated);  // sizeof(char) is 1
    do {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        // if our buffer is too small, double the allocation 
        if (counter + 2 <= allocated) {
            size_t new_size = allocated * 2;
            char *new_buffer = realloc(string, new_size);
            if (! new_buffer) {
                // out of memory? try smaller increment
                new_size = allocated + 16;
                new_buffer = realloc(string, new_size);
                if (! new_buffer) {
                    // really out of memory: free old block
                    free(string);
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
            allocated = new_size;
            string = new_buffer;
        }
        // store the character
        string[counter++] = c;
    } while (c != '\n');

    // terminate the buffer properly
    string[counter - 1] = '\0';
    return string;
}

int main() {
    char *s = uinput();
    if (!s) {
        // possibly out of memory in uinput
        perror("Error reading input");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("\nYou entered: %s", s);
    free(s);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hope I didn't do too much UB in mine. I think I have to provide a PD getline implementation :D

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer :D So much more stuff i need to learn about C.
BTW can you explain EOF? First time i've seen it

Comment: End-of-file. If you press `ctrl-d` in Linux, or `ctrl-z` on windows; or if you want to use this kind of approach for files (you can use `fgetc` instead of `getchar`)

Comment: [See this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782080/what-is-eof-in-the-c-programming-language)

Comment: Never call `realloc` like this: `name = realloc(name, newSize)` - it it fails then you have a memory leak - use a temporary pointer until you know whether `realloc` succeeded or not.

Comment: If realloc failed, null pointer was returned and the program has UB. Then the memory leak is least of worries :D

Comment: Sure, but better not to set a bad example which will be copied and pasted unquestioningly by noobs. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR The thing is, I do not know what to do when *that* realloc fails, except exit with `perror`

Comment: Doubling the size of the buffer each time you need more memory is not necessary. On modern `malloc` implementations, it is not much faster than just incrementing buffer size by 1 each time you read a character.

Comment: @HAL9000 the speed of the `malloc` is not the issue here. It is the amount of memory that needs to be copied around in *`realloc`*.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think this is the problem

you are re-allocing

`realloc(string, counter * sizeof(char));`

The what will be the size of string in first iteration? It will be `0`.

Now you are writing to a pointer which has 0 bytes allocated and hence segfault.

Changing it to a `while loop` can help to fix it. You can also change the initial value of counter to fix it

Comment: well spotted indeed :D I just tried changing the counter to 1 though, but the program is still crashing(not responding)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person{
    char *name;
}pers;

void addMem(void);

int main(void){
    addMem();

    printf("\nYour name is:>  %s\n",pers.name);
    free(pers.name);
    pers.name = NULL;
    return 0;
}

void addMem(void){
    unsigned int length = 6;
    size_t newLength = 0;
    unsigned int newSize = 0;
    unsigned int i =0;
    char *name;
    int c;

    name = malloc(length);
    if(name == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    newSize = length;

    printf("Enter your name:>  ");

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c!=EOF){
        name[i++]=(char)c;

        if(i == newSize){
            newSize = i+length;
            name = realloc(name, newSize);
        }
    }

    name[i] = '\0';

    newLength = strlen(name)+1;
    pers.name = malloc(newLength);

    memcpy(pers.name, name, newLength);

    free(name);
    name = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Never call `realloc` like this: `name = realloc(name, newSize)` - it it fails then you have a memory leak - use a temporary pointer until you know whether `realloc` succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `fgets()`, which gets a string into a sized buffer from the input stream; if it has the complete input then the string ends with `\n`; if it doesn't then it doesn't.  So you can loop calling fgets until there is an EOL character at the end, then depending on what your program does with the input you can decide whether to keep realloc-ing or to process the input a bit at a time.

Answer (score 0):

use `getchar`, `malloc` and `realloc` for reading the unlimited input string

Declare String type, you can also use `char *`

```
// String type
typedef char *String;
```

I write this function for joining the char in the end of string

```
/**
 * Join the Char into end of String
 *
 * @param string - String
 * @param c - joined char
 */
void String_joinChar(String *string, const char c)
{
  const size_t length = strlen(*string);
  (*string) = (String)realloc((*string), sizeof(char) * (length + 2));
  (*string)[length] = c;
  (*string)[length + 1] = '\0';
}
```

This function for inputting string, which read the char from keyboard by using `getchar` and join it in the end of current string.

```
/**
 * Input String
 *
 * @return Inputed String
 */
String String_input()
{
  String string = (String)malloc(sizeof(char));
  strcpy(string, "");

  char cursor;
  fflush(stdin);
  while ((cursor = getchar()) != '\n' && cursor != EOF)
  {
    String_joinChar(&string, cursor);
  }

  return string;
}
```

Cause of using `char *`, `malloc` and `realloc`, we must free it

```
/**
 * Destroy String
 *
 * @param string - Destroyed String
 */
void String_destroy(String string)
{
  free(string);
}
```

And now we just use it !!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  String string = String_input();
  printf("\n%s\n", string);
  String_destroy(string);
  return 0;
}
```

Hope useful to you!

Comment: *`int cursor`*!!