# NULL Terminator in text files

Tags: c, input, command-line, null-terminated

I am creating a program that reads in the contents of a text file through the command line, character by character.

Is the NULL value automatically inserted or do I have to add it to the text file manually?

Comment: Instead of NULL, you can simply use EOF, which means end of file and it's inserted automatically. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782080/what-is-eof-in-the-c-programming-language]

Comment: `NULL` is a macro with a _null pointer constant_. There is no `NULL` character or a null pointer constant in text files. It is not clear what you mean. Please see [ask] and add more information to your question, including your code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text *files* do not need to have a terminator on modern platforms. (On some legacy platforms they did have one, but I doubt it is the case here.) You almost certainly should not write a terminator into the file, as it may cause problems with programs that do not expect one. The end of file serves as a terminator when reading.

Text *strings* in C are arrays of characters terminated by a zero, aka the null character, mnemonic NUL (with one L, and it is not the same thing as `NULL` in C). When creating strings, you do need to terminate them correctly. Functions returning strings, including ones that read them from files (e.g., `fgets`), terminate them for you.

Comment: @Norman that legacy terminator *in the text file* was not `NULL` but for example, `Ctrl-Z` or `0x1A`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, I know, that's why I didn't specify null terminator but simply "a terminator". Anyway, I don't think it is relevant to the question, just a bit of trivia. =)

Comment: sorry remark was to OP who asked "is NULL value automatically inserted or do I have to add it to the text file manually", so perhaps relevant to the question.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you :)