# When I open a python shell in powershell, I cannot close it

Tags: python, powershell

When I open a python shell in PowerShell, I cannot close it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. I swore it worked before, it works in VS Code's terminal as well, so I'm not quite sure what is wrong with powershell. The only way to exit is using the quit() function.

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, I get

```sh
KeyboardInterrupt
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> gets me

```
^d
```

and likewise for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

Info:

- Windows 10
- python 3.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1782134/9171697), `eof` on Windows is different from *nix.

It is <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> on Windows that gives you end of file, not <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.

Therefore, press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>**enter**</kbd> should do the trick.

Comment: unfortunately Crtl + z does not work for some reason, it just inputs ```^Z```

Comment: @AndrewLi Did you press enter?