# Why doesn't this while loop go on forever? Beginner C question

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

```
#define MAXLINE 1000
char pattern[] = "ould";
main()
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int found = 0;

    while (getline(line,MAXLINE) > 0)
       if (strindex(line, pattern) >= 0 ) {
          printf("%s", line);
          found ++;
       }
    return found
}
```

Why does that while loop go on forever? getline(line,1000) would, as I barely understand it, return the length of the line, and "append it" (?) to MAXLINE, making a number larger than 1000, depending on the line length...  why would that ever dip below zero?

I read that getline returns -1 if "unsuccessful", when would that be? When would line not be read?

This is on page 69 of Kernighan. I've been skipping around the book, and I'm currently backtracking to see where I missed something.

"Describe what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually resulted. Minimum 20 characters."

Comment: What happens when `stdin` is closed? Either by hitting Ctrl-D or by having it piped from a file that ends?

Comment: Is `getline` a function that you have defined yourself? If that is the case, then please show us the code of that function.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel `getline` is a function that pops up a couple times in K&R/2e (chapters 1 & 4).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thank you! This is it, getline is defined in the standard library a totally different way than in the book. Appreciated, all! (er; how do I mark as solved?)

Comment: @FidgetyMeditation: The ISO C standard library does not define a function with the name `getline` at all. However, POSIX platforms (e.g. Linux) do define a function by that name. But you are correct that this definition is different from the one in the K&R book. The most similar function in the ISO C standard library is probably the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: *I've been skipping around the book* - Stop doing that, and start from the beginning and work your way through. Skipping around means that you miss important concepts. Also, you need to provide a [mre] here, and that includes all the code that you've written (whether it's from the book or not), so that we can see if you've introduced a typo or missed a line. Any code that is not part of the standard libraries should be in your post.

Comment: Why are you trying to learn modern C from K&R C?

Comment: Skipping the whole book might be the better idea indeed. It's as outdated as a computer from the 1970s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the `getline` and `strindex` defined in the book:

```
/* getline: get line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    i = 0;
    while (--lim > 0 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* strindex: return index of t in s, -1 if none */
int strindex(char s[], char t[])
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j=i, k=0; t[k] != '\0' && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
            ;
        if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As you can see `getline` reads until it reaches end of file(EOF).
If you are running the program on the command-line, your program is waiting for this signal from standard in, you can send this signal manually by pressing Control-d.

if you cat a file into the program:

```
$ cat test.txt | ./your program
```

the end of file value it sent, at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The version of `getline` shown on page 69 of K&R Second Edition is defined as:

```
/* getline: get line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    i = 0;
    while (--lim > 0 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

From this we can see that one of the conditions that must be met for the function to continue consuming characters from the `stdin` stream is that the returned character does not equal the constant value `EOF`.

```
(c=getchar()) != EOF
```

`EOF`, or [*end-of-file*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file), indicates that there is no more data to be read from the stream. See [What is EOF in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1782080/2505965) for additional details.

In the event that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns `EOF` the very first time it is called in `getline`, `i` will never increment beyond `0`, and the function will return zero.

This version of `getline` cannot return `-1`.

The condition you have shown

```
while (getline(line,MAXLINE) > 0)
```

will cause this loop to stop when the return value is *less than* or *equal* to zero. In other words, when `getline` indicates it has read no data.

Comment: FWIW, `getline(s, length_less_than_2)` is UB.